# How to modify XML embedded on a webpage using selenium on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, selenium

I am looking to use selenium and python to modify XML which has been embedded on a webpage. For example, I have a webpage which contains the following data:
[image]

And I would like to have a script which modifies "*Existing Value*" to "*New Value*"

Has anybody been able to make this work?

Comment: Can you share that xml in text format, I will make a local script and see if I can help.

Comment: share the xml as text and the requested output as text

Comment: Have you written any code so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` to locate and extract the XML, create an `xml.etree.ElementTree` from the string, and then use recursion to update the tree. Once the update is complete, you can write the transformed XML back to field on the page:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.yourwebpage.com')
xml_source = d.execute_script('''
  return document.querySelector('#xml-field').value //substitute `#xml-field` with the css path to the XML box
  //if the XML box is not an input field, use `element.textContent` instead of `element.value`
''')
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_source)
def update_tree(node):
   if node.text == 'Existing Value':
      node.text = "New Value"
   for i in node:
      update_tree(i)

update_tree(tree)
new_tree = ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml').decode()
d.execute_script(f'''
   return document.querySelector('#xml-field').value = '{new_tree}' //write updated tree back to box
''')
```